# Email aliases in Gmail app

Tags: email, gmail, accounts

My university gives me an email that looks like

ab123456@domain

Fortunately, I am allowed to make an alternate name for my email, like

first.last@domain

All of the email is still sent through ab123456. In fact, when I set up the SMTP settings, I have to use this address. On my desktop client, I can send emails that say that they were sent from first.last. Is there a way of doing this in the new Gmail app?

I am using the new Gmail app (which absorbed the Email app) in Android 5.0.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: As I have the same issue, I've just tried without success to find a way to do it in gmail app..But discovered that you can easily do it in Email app built in my samsung device..

Answer (score 3):

Proper aliases, where you can pick either address as the sender, isn't possible in Gmail. However, in your case I understand you never want to use `ab123456@domain`; you *always* want to use `first.last@domain`.

In that case, when adding a new account, use `first.last@domain` as your email address and choose manual setup. Enter your password when prompted and then, in the incoming server settings, change your username to `ab123456@domain`. Enter all other settings and do the same for the outgoing server.

Now you have email setup for your account that will always use `first.last@domain` when sending email. It will of course read email sent to either.

Comment: Thanks for the partial workaround. It's crazy that Android's built-in email app doesn't support aliases. It makes it unusable for me, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can send emails from Gmail through multiple accounts and set the account that you want.  I use `myusername@gmail.com`, and `myworkemail@myworkdomain`, both going through my Gmail app. When I compose an email, I change the email address under "From".  However, to get that, I changed the settings on the web to allow me to control access to that account.  I might be wrong.

If you want to try it, you can go to **Settings > Accounts and Import** on the web and look under **Send Mail As**.  You can then add another email address that you own, which would be your `first.name@domain` email address.  I believe that would work.  I don't know if anyone else has a better idea, but that's what I do.  I know my example uses two different domains, but the principle is the same.

Comment: You are referring to distinct mailboxes. The OP is referring to aliases that share a single mailbox. Gmail supports this for their own service, but not 3rd party.