# Sending email from an alias using Gmail app

Tags: gmail

I use G-Suite for business. I have the main domain (Let's call it example.com) and a number of secondary domains (we'll use example.co.uk for this). I have set up aliases so that I can receive email sent to joe.user@example.com and also joe.user@example.co.uk.

Using GMail on the web I can select a default email address for outgoing email. So, although my primary address is joe.user@example.com my outgoing email appears to come from joe.user@example.co.uk

So far, so good.

Now I want to do the same thing on my Android phone and tablet.

**How can I set up Gmail for Android to use my alias joe.user@example.co.uk instead of my primary address joe.user@example.com?**

Note that I don't want to reset the phone and sign in with a different address. I just want to change the GMail alias.

One answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/89015/324644) suggests it's not possible, but that was five years ago. Has anything changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not possible if you use Gmail app.

Alternatively, you can use [FairEmail](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2605/131553) ( link to the community ads promotion), which let's you do this and has *many* more features available.

I use  Gmail aliases with this app (not affiliated to it) . You can refer to the extensive app [FAQ](https://github.com/M66B/FairEmail/blob/master/FAQ.md#user-content-faq9) 
in case of issues or join the active app forum on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/newreply.php?do=postreply&t=3824168)

Comment: I suspected as much. I was just hoping that I might have missed something in a settings menu somewhere. I'll post something to the black hole that is Google's Help & Feedback system and see what happens. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thanks. May as well leave a link here for the feature request (or edit into answer), so that others can "star" it